# Ruby on Rails, script/delayed job start. nothing happens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using following gems:

```
gem 'daemons', "=1.0.10"
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

and following command to delay the method:

after_create :perform_analysis
 handle_asynchronously :perform_analysis, :run_at => Proc.new { 1.minutes.from_now }

script/delayed_job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

So, I start the application with usual rails s (in tmp/pids appears a file server.pid). Upload some stuff, so the create method is invoked. Some data is inserted into delayed_jobs table. I close stop running the server(in tmp/pids exists nothing!).

Then I write into a command line:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

Response:
in tmp/pids appeard delayed_job.pid and terminal shows me nothing, so I run:

```
 kik@kik-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/tors15.01$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job status
pid-file for killed process 8695 found (/home/kik/Desktop/tors15.01/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid), deleting.
delayed_job: no instances running
```

and again trying my luck:

```
kik@kik-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/tors15.01$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
kik@kik-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/tors15.01$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run
pid-file for killed process 8718 found (/home/kik/Desktop/tors15.01/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid), deleting.
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: delayed_jobs: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_by = null, locked_at = null WHERE (locked_by = 'delayed_job host:kik-VirtualBox pid:8724')
```

When I tun `rake jobs:work` it is working

What is the reason for this ot where do I do a mistake?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure about setting the rails environment to production?

```
script/delayed_job start
```

or

```
RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job start
```